# how to check type of provided api field while unmarshaling JSON

Tags: json, api, go

How can I unmarshal a JSON response where a empty field value returns as a string from server and other times returns as object?

```
{
"replies": "" // empty field from server
}
```

Server with some replies

```
    {
    "replies": {
    "author" : "fooname"
    }
    }
```

golang unmarshaling error as cannot convert string to type Replies

Comment: You can implement the unmarshaler interface on your Replies type and have it unmarshal anything you like.

Comment: I couldnt find a way to implement UnmarshalJSON () method for replies as it is deep down in json data provided by server. Could you provide an example for this. I was able to find https://gist.github.com/tkrajina/aec8d1b15b088c20f0df4afcd5f0c511 this gist so far, but they provided a way to unmarshal top level json

Comment: You can implement `UnmarshalJSON` on any subset (struct) of a larger struct

Comment: @Adrian both question have different use cases. Its not duplicate. The question you suggested have use case of getting reaponse of distinct type. In here replies contains an object.

Comment: @JohnMcLane it's not precisely identical but the differences are irrelevant to the problem and the solution is the same.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface to handle this case.

Assuming we start with these structs, we can see that the field that needs custom logic is of type `Replies`:

```
type Response struct {
    Replies Replies `json:"replies"`
}

type Replies struct {
    *realResp
}

// Contains actual data
type realResp struct {
    Author string `json:"author"`
}
```

Now we can implement the `UnmarshalJSON` method:

```
func (r *Replies) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if string(b) == "\"\"" {
        return nil // Do nothing; you might also want to return an error
    }
    r.realResp = &realResp{} // Initialize r.realResp
    return json.Unmarshal(b, r.realResp)
}
```

Note the pointer receiver so UnmarshalJSON can modify `r`.

You can also see [this full example](https://play.golang.org/p/t-_PAJCAX4-).

Comment: Thanks I was able to get through this error but there is another problem with your solution as I couldn't unmarshal lets say suppose array of Author. Can you help me with this ??

Comment: You can replace `realResp` with whatever type you want to. You could use `[]realResp` instead of `*realResp` in the struct definition, which would then be an array/slice of these elements. If this doesn't help you can post the JSON you want to parse

Answer (score -2):

As golang is strictly typed, replies cannot have 2 types (string and object)

replies should return an object or null if there is none. This code might be helpful to understand.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type replies struct {
    Author string `json:"author"`
}

type resp struct {
    Replies *replies `json:"replies"`
}

func main() {
    obj := new(resp)
    response := []byte(`{"replies": {"author":"fooname"}}`)
    //response := []byte(`{"replies": null}`)

    err := json.Unmarshal(response, obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if obj.Replies != nil {
        fmt.Println(obj.Replies.Author)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Empty replies")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if they don't have control over whoever generates the JSON

Comment: It's also just not true. There are ways to deal with JSON with inconsistent structure.